# How do I use sails command line generators in my node code?

Tags: node.js, command-line, code-generation, sails.js

Wondering how to do the following sails command-line generators:

```
sails generate api
sails generate model
sails generate controller
```

I would love to be able to require it in a file so then I could access it's functionality in my code based on a programmatic decision. This is for my document driven development solution with sails. Where markdown documentation based on APIary's Blueprint standard will be used with my code to generate the sails api code and test the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe this link will make u more understand, actually you can modify the generator console command. Check out [this generators](https://github.com/irlnathan/sails-generate-scaffold)